# I'm having trouble linking an image from a different folder

Tags: html, image, url

```
<head>
<title> URL Practice </Title>

</head>

<body>

<img src = "./bloo/chicken.png"> 

</body>
```

I'm trying to learn how to do relative URL links and I've been trying to get it to link to an image from a folder that's inside the original file. It's not working and I don't understand why, I feel like I've tried every variation.

[This is what I'm working with if that helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4SMK.jpg)

Also I'm really new to this, so if you can explain it to me like you would a 3 year old, that would be awesome because that's probably where my level of expertise is.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the image is in the "bloo" folder. Your HTML file and the bloo folder are both children to the root folder. For you to link to link the image, you need to need to reference it like this

```
src="bloo/imagename.jpg"
```

it will reference it correctly that way.

So your code snipest will look like

```
    <img src="bloo/chicken.jpg"/>
```

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

enter code here

HTML Input src Attribute

\